# React native set state to true for one second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a state:

```
state = {
showView: false,
}
```

How can I make a function that when called it changes the `showView` state to `true` for 1 second then change it back to false?

Comment: Have you tried using `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.setState({
  showView: true,
}, () => setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    showView: false,
  })
}, 1000))
```

This will set the state back to false after briefly (1 second) set it to true, using the React setState callback function.